# How to start a Java Jar file the right way from a website with parameters

Tags: java, jar

I want to start a Java Jar file from a website with parameters like e.g. ID. There are two main questions. So the user goes on the website, clicks on a button and the Jar file starts.

1. The first question is how to get the jar started after clicking a button.
2. The second question is about the blocking of java jar files. If I go to [www.quickscreenshare.com](http://www.quickscreenshare.com) for example, chrome blocks the plugin. I have to give permission to the execution of the jar and sometimes I also have to restart the browser after that permission. Is there a way to start the jar directly without this annoying permission stuff?

**What is the best way to add a jar execution to a button?**

Comment: Are you talking about a java applet running in the browser?

Comment: I'm not sure if I should use an Applet or a Jar execution. I know for now that I need to sign my Application to not get blocked. My application includes socket connections, remote control and voip.

Comment: I recommend to read more about the basics for Applets, Web Start and other techniques first. The question as it currently is seems too broad.

Comment: Of course I already red about the basics for Applets but the questions I have are not that trivial. I don't think it is too broad because basically it is just the question "how to start a jar file with parameters in a webpage" or is there another way.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, neither with nor without additional parameters.

Generic Java archive files (JAR) can not be launched in the normal JRE on the users client.

You can only

- use an Applet which runs in the web browser Java plugin sandbox, and gets its parameters from the hosting HTML page source
- launch a Java Web Start application from the command line when it has been downloaded once - in this case no browser plugin is required

For details about security prompts see

http://java.com/en/download/help/appsecuritydialogs.xml

Comment: Quickscreenshare is also starting a jar file in the browser, as far as I understand it. yED uses jnlp to start their app in the browser. I'm not sure if I better should use jar/jnlp or applet. Is a signed java applet able to use createScreenCapture, create a socket connection to a server and allows me to use audio input and output?

Comment: Quickscreen share also uses parameters. You can see them here: http://quickscreenshare.com/js/quickshare.js